# python calling method within a method

Tags: python, oop

Here is my code which works.

```
class S:
    def doSomething():
        for j in headers:
             for z in j:
                 st = str(z).strip()
                 stringValue = st.replace('\n', "")
                 headerArr.append(stringValue)

         return headerArr
```

I would like to replace the above code with this.

```
class S:
    def cleanStr(self, stringVal):
        st = stringVal.strip()
        stringValue = st.replace('\n', "")
        return stringValue

    def doSomething():
        for j in headers:
            for z in j:
                newString = self.cleanStr(z)
                headerArr.append(newString)

        return headerArr
```

But when I try to run this new code I get name 'self' is not defined. I apologize in advance for any mistakes with indentation. In another file I have something like newArr = s.doSomething().It works with the first code snippet. But not with the second.I have tried doing def doSomething(self): and then in the other file I do newArr = s.doSomething(self) but I still get the same error.

Comment: Are your methods part of a class definition or are they methods that just stand alone ie utility functions?

Comment: Just as you include `self` in the `cleanStr` definition, you also need to include it in the `doSomething` definition. Which also means you have to call `doSomething` as a method on some instance, of course.

Comment: `newString = cleanStr(z)` without `self` and `def cleanStr(stringVal)` also without `self` , and stop using `camelCase` in python you need to use `under_score`

Comment: Is there a class involved? `doSomething` needs to take `self` as its first argument if it is a method.

Comment: @GantTheWanderer The question says "Also these methods are inside of a class I created."

Comment: It's worth noting that `cleanStr` doesn't actually do anything with `self`, and `doSomething` doesn't do anything with `self` except to use it to call `cleanStr`, so there's really no _point_ to putting these in a class. But if you really want to, you can do it anyway; you just have to get the details right.

Comment: Meanwhile, since more than half the comments are asking whether these are in a class, you probably want to edit your question to make this more prominent than an "Also…" at the very end. Ideally, change your example to show a `class Whatever:` and the methods indented within. It may not do anything to get back all of the downvotes, but it's still worth doing.

Comment: Ok I will edit the question. My understanding was that in order to call cleanStr inside doSomething I need to do it like this -> self.cleanStr(). But that doesn't seem to be working. adding self to doSomething so its like def doSomething(self):, still gives me the same error

Comment: Can we get the whole class?

Comment: @ray I sincerely doubt it gives you the same error, unless whatever _calls_ this method is _also_ trying to pass an undefined `self`. I'd be willing to bet it actually gives you a different error, like a `TypeError` about missing 1 positional parameter—but that's just a guess without seeing the code that calls it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, methods only get a `self` parameter if you explicitly declare it. You've already done that for `cleanStr`; you just need to do the same for `doSomething`:

```
class Spam:
    def cleanStr(self, stringVal):
        st = stringVal.strip()
        stringValue = st.replace('\n', "")
        return stringValue

    def doSomething(self):
        for j in headers:
            for z in j:
                newString = self.cleanStr(z)
                headerArr.append(newString)
```

Now, `self` is defined, as a parameter, so you can use it to call `self.cleanStr` without getting a `NameError`.

It's worth noting that, as written, this code will only work if `headers` and `headerArr` are global variables somewhere else in your code.

Also, this means you can only call `doSomething` on a `Spam` instance:

```
headers = [('abc', 'def\n', '\ng\nh\ni\n'), ('abc', 'def')]
headerArr = []
spam = Spam()
spam.doSomething()
assert headerArr == ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'abc', 'def']
```

You can see this working [on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ScalyLonePorts).

---

This is a very weird interface. You've got two methods on `Spam` that don't actually do anything with `self`, but instead read from some global sequence and append onto some global list. I can't imagine where this would be useful. But if you want to do it anyway, you can; you just need to get the details right.

If you want an idea of what it looks like to actually use a class, and therefore to be worth having a class and methods instead of a bunch of just separate functions, maybe something like this:

```
class Spam:
    def __init__(self):
        self.headerArr = []

    def cleanStr(self, stringVal):
        st = stringVal.strip()
        stringValue = st.replace('\n', "")
        return stringValue

    def doSomething(self, headers):
        for j in headers:
            for z in j:
                newString = self.cleanStr(z)
                self.headerArr.append(newString)

spam = Spam()
spam.doSomething([('abc', 'def\n', '\ng\nh\ni\n'), ('abc', 'def')])
spam.doSomething([('abc\n', 'def\n')])
assert spam.headerArr == ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'abc', 'def', 'abc', 'def']
```

---

Your "version which works" doesn't really work, except by accident:

```
class S:
    def doSomething():
        for j in headers:
             for z in j:
                 st = str(z).strip()
                 stringValue = st.replace('\n', "")
                 headerArr.append(stringValue)
```

You can't call this on an instance of `S`, or you'll get a `TypeError: doSomething() missing 1 required positional argument: 'headers'`. You *can* call it as just `S.doSomething()`, but only because Python 3 happens to use plain function objects for unbound methods, which means that, as long as you never create an instance, you can kind of use them as static methods. But this is not a reasonable thing to do. If you really want a static method, declare one with `@staticmethod`. But usually, you don't; you just want a function, at module scope. You're effectively abusing `S` as a submodule here, rather than as a class.

Comment: I am still not getting it to work. I am doing def doSomething(self), and then in the file where I am calling it I am doing obj = S(). obj.doSomething(). I am getting it to work this way if I don't call cleanStr inside doSomething.

Comment: @ray I've added a link to an online interpreter where you can see the code working. You've clearly done something else wrong, but I can't guess what that might be from your description.

Comment: I got it to work. I simplified the code I posted because I thought it would be easier to debug. When I did self.cleanStr(z) I actually needed to do self.cleanStr(str(z)). Combined with what you suggested it is now working, thanks for your help  I will try to ask better questions in the future.

Comment: @ray You also need to be able to recognize different errors. If you needed `str(z)`, that means `z` wasn't a string, so the error is probably something like `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip'`. That's not the same error as `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`. The error includes useful information, that you have to be able to understand if you want to debug your code, or at least be able to show other people if you want them to help you debug your code.

Comment: Yes your right. Originally it was a name 'self' is not defined. but after that there was TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable, but in my confusion I saw it as a TypeError I encountered before when I forgot to add self into the method definition